# How to run war procfile on heroku

Tags: heroku

Please give your suggestions. I have deployed my first war file on heroku and want to run that but I am not getting the way to run this. I have tried the command below in CMD prompt into my app directory.

```
heroku open
```

and gettin the eroor: HTTP Status 404- The requested resource is not available.

Comment: what heroku log says

Comment: Please extend your question with more information about your application and deployment steps that you have taken and directory contents.